# Boost Dijkstra shortest: path modify graph dynamically inside visitor

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using the 'dijkstra_shortest_paths()' function from BGL and a custom visitor. For my application I need to extend the graph dynamically inside the 'examine_vertex()' method of the visitor during the shortest path search. Especially, some addidional vertexes and edges from the currently examined vertex might be added.

This seems not to work at all, since the newly added edges are not considered by the Dijkstra implementation.

Is there any way to make it work with BGL?

Regards

Comment: You need to design your own algorithm that doesn't assume the same invariants. That can be hard and will probably lead to algorithms that might not terminate.

Comment: Actually I already have a working implementation, I just wanted to use BGL now. So I assume it is not possible?

Comment: Possible? Maybe. Supported? No.